# How do I prove a ball plus a vector keeps some lineal properties?

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Let V be a vectorial space with a norm, and $A\subset V$ any set. We are defining sum of vector plus a set like this:
$x+A:= \{z\in V: z+a, a\in A\}$ and $\lambda A:=\{ z\in V: z=\lambda a, a\in A\}$   with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R\circ C} $

i)prove that $B(a,r) =a + B(0,r)$

ii)prove that $\alpha B(a,r) =\alpha a + \alpha B(0,r) = \star$

and ofc $B$ is a ball $B(a,r)=\{ x\in V : ||x-a||<r \}$

$\star$theres another ball here but it's sadly unreadable in my notebook if someone seen it it would be much appreciated

Thanks for reading all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example with $\;(i)\;$ :

$$x\in B(0,r)\implies ||x||<r\implies ||(a+x)-a||=||x||<r\implies a+x\in B(a,r)$$
and on the other hand

$$x\in B(a,r)\implies ||x-a||<r\implies x=a+(x-a)\in a+B(0,r)$$

Comment: i still dont understand the last part of the "on the other hand", how does dat mean they are in the B(0,r)?

Comment: Is it clear that $\;x=a+(x-a)\;$ ? Well, since $\;x-a\in B(a,r)\;$ , then we're done!

Comment: Oh i was so blocked, now i see it. o.O thx for your help.